# how to get a value from sqlite and show it in a edittext

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext, cursor

this is mi function cursor in my class DataBaseManager

```
 public Cursor cargarid()
{
    String [] columna=new String[]{columna_ID_producto};

    return db.query(Table_Name_productos,columna,null,null,"desc","LIMIT","1");

}
```

now how can i get the result. 
i need the result in my fragment.

```
 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

     manager = new DataBaseManager(getActivity());
     cursor=manager.cargarid();
 final EditText clave = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.et_clave);e
clave.settext("the value from sqlite??");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor = manager.cargarid();
cursor.moveToFirst();
final EditText clave = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.et_clave);
clave.settext(cursor.getString(0));
```

Comment: you also must explain in words, what the code is trying to do, and how it is helping solving a problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code to get value from sqllite

```
 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

 manager = new DataBaseManager(getActivity());
 Cursor cursor=manager.cargarid();
 final EditText clave = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.et_clave);

 if(cursor.getCount > 0)
 {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    clave.settext("sql lite value" +cursor.getString(0));
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your DatabaseManager Class make new method like below:

```
public ArrayList getDataFromdatabase(){

    ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String [] columna=new String[]{columna_ID_producto};
    Cursor c = db.query(Table_Name_productos,columna,null,null,"desc","LIMIT","1");

    c.moveTofirst();

    while(c.isAfterLast() == false){
         array_list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
          c.moveToNext();
     }
     return array_list;
  }
```

To get All data from database and show into your listview you just need to call this method from your fragment and add this into your custom adapter.

```
Arraylist list= databasemanager.getDataFromdatabase();
```